# Is there a way to check if the ValueEventListener removed successfully?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an Android application wherein I wanna check for changes in Firebase Database. However, I just wanna listen for changes in the database up till 5 changes are made. After that, I wanna close the valueEventListener.

```
valueEventListener = databaseReference.child(roomID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(i == 5){
                Log.d(TAG,"REMOVING");
                databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG,"CALLED");
            }
            i++;
        }
```

So after this, I go to Firebase and manually change the values. For the first five changes made, "CALLED" is printed in logs 5 times, and for the 6th change "REMOVING" is printed. So I suppose it won't print anymore for changes made further. But even after that, as I change the values in firebase it keeps printing "CALLED" in logs. So I'm confused, did the connection close, or is it still open and listening to changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing the listener from the wrong reference. To solve this, please change:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

To:

```
databaseReference.child(roomID).removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
//                 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Even if you remove the listener correctly, "REMOVING" will be printed out once, since you detach the listener after that log statement.

Comment: Oh, sorry for stupid question, i didn't know about that. Thanks alot. It worked :)